# Resolve the address using the appropriate function and print out the complete host information

Tags: c#, dns

***EDITED CODE***This is what I have so far. The IP address is the same no matter what website I put in. What do I have to do to resolve everything in the topic title? I appreciate any help because I really don't know how to proceed!!***EDITED CODE***

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace CSDNS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void PrintHostInfo(String host)
        {
            {
                IPHostEntry hostinfo;

                try
                {
                    IPHostEntry hostInfo;

                    //Attempt to resolve DNS for given host or address
                    hostInfo = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

                    //Display the primary host name
                    Console.WriteLine("\tCanonical Name: " + hostInfo.HostName);

                    //Display list of IP addresses for this host
                    Console.WriteLine("\tIP Addresses:  ");
                    foreach (IPAddress ipaddr in hostInfo.AddressList)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t{0} ", ipaddr);
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine();

                    //Display list of alias names for this host
                    Console.Write("\tAliases:       ");
                    foreach (String alias in hostInfo.Aliases)
                    {
                        Console.Write(alias + " ");
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tUnable to resolve host: " + host + "\n");
                }
            }
        }

        static void Main()
        {
            //Get and print local host info
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Local Host:");
                String localHostName = Dns.GetHostAddresses();
                Console.WriteLine("\tHost Name:      " + localHostName);

                PrintHostInfo(localHostName);
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unable to resolve local host\n");
            }

            //Get and print info for hosts given on command line 
            foreach (String arg in new[] { "www.sunybroome.edu" })
            {
                Console.WriteLine(arg + ":");
                PrintHostInfo(arg);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, I went to whatismyip and it is different. The ip address that comes up in this program is 192.168.1.143 no matter the website. I'm very unfamiliar with c# so I don't know what to do.

Comment: thnx type of IP address you are looking is in `Router`! If you need your WAN Ip just parse it from whatismyip.com

Comment: hmm thanks for the response but I'm not quite sure what you mean. The program should be pulling the host information for google.com since that is what I have in the code.

Comment: have a look at the code below!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    static void PrintHostInfo(String host)
    {
        {
            IPHostEntry hostinfo;

            try
            {
                //Attempt to resolve DNS for given host or address
                IPAddress[] hostInfo = Dns.GetHostAddresses(host);

                //Display list of IP addresses for this host
                Console.WriteLine("\tIP Addresses:  ");
                foreach (IPAddress ipaddr in hostInfo)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t{0} ", ipaddr);
                }

                Console.WriteLine("\n-------------------------------------\n\n");
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tUnable to resolve host: " + host + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        //Get and print local host info
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Local Host:");
            String localHostName = Dns.GetHostAddresses("localhost")[0].ToString();
            Console.WriteLine("\tHost Name:      " + localHostName);

            PrintHostInfo(localHostName);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to resolve local host\n");
        }

        //Get and print info for hosts given on command line 
        foreach (String arg in new[] { "www.sunybroome.edu" })
        {
            Console.WriteLine(arg + ":");
            PrintHostInfo(arg);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. Seriously. Is there any way you can check back on this topic in a little bit? I have to modify this code to do something different and you obviously know what you're doing!! Thanks again.

Comment: I needed to use both GetHostEntry (which you thankfully helped me fix), as well as GetHostAddresses. I am getting an error code when I swap the 2.. "Error 1 - Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Net.IPAddress[]' to 'System.Net.IPHostEntry' ". "Error 2 - No overload for method 'GetHostAddresses' takes 0 arguments". Once again, my head is spinning. Thanks in advance for taking your time!!  *EDIT* to be more specific, 1 program runs GetHostEntry, 1 program runs GetHostAddresses and 1 program to run both. I am trying to get the program to run just GetHostAddresses right now.

Comment: `GetHostAddresses` is same as `GetHostEntry("hostname").AddressList`

Comment: Actually.. I'm confused. GetHostEntry is just supposed to get the Host Name, right? GetHostAddresses is to get the IP address. I already have all of that in the code that you gave me, but it didn't use GetHostAddresses()?

Comment: No, `GetHostEntry` gets the `hostname + addresses` too, the Addresses is stored as property in `IPHostEntry.AddressList`

Comment: once again, thanks a million!!!! Going to give you a ton of reputation, thanks. Now I just have to work on combining the 2, which I think I should be able to do by myself, but I will really appreciate again if you wouldn't mind to check back just in case. You have literally saved the day. Now to combine all the code you gave me..